# Как запустить npm чтобы не лез никуда кроме дочерних папок?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, hosting

Есть шаред хостинг просто фтп пхп и тд., там есть SSH, но очень урезаны права. Я могу исполнить свои js файлы нодой, могу пользоватся полноценно git, для композера могу скачать composer.phar и запускать его тоже все работает.
npm там тоже стоит но не могу его запустить потому что он зачем то лезет туда куда нет доступа.

```
npm init
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.local'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:83:20
    at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:214:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:252:24
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:80:13
    at f (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:178:20)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:235:20)
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205
  if (npm.config.get('json')) {
                 ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:374:26)
```

Есть какой нибудь способ чтобы это работало, либо мб как с компрозером просто отдельный файл npm.js который кину в корень проекта, или как то переназначить для себя эти служебные директории чтобы они были там где есть доступ.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть какой нибудь способ чтобы это работало, либо мб как с компрозером просто отдельный файл npm.js который кину в корень проекта, или как то переназначить для себя эти служебные директории чтобы они были там где есть доступ.

Вот такой чеклист:

1. Сделайте бэкап ваших данных.
2. Создайте директорию в домашней `mkdir ~/.npm-global`
3. Задайте npm новый путь `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
4. Пропишите путь к директории export `PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
5. Команда `source ~/.profile`
6. Готово `npm install -g your-package`

или

Вместо пунктов 2-4: `NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global`

---

[Офф. сайт](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)