# Почему возникают ошибки при установке Gulp в mac OS High Sierra?

Tags: gulp

В процессе установки gulp получил множество ошибок, род и причину которых понять не могу. Что не так? Как установить правильно?

MacBook-Pro-Oleg:skinali 1ego$ sudo npm i gulp -g
Password:
/usr/local/bin/gulp -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js

> fsevents@1.2.7 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents
>   node install

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.7 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents/lib' 
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/Users/1ego/.node-gyp/10.15.3"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

- gulp@4.0.0
  added 317 packages from 218 contributors in 22.759s

Comment: Посмотрите ответ (там же есть ссылка на оф. документацию) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849943/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-npm-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA

Comment: Спасибо! Единственное, можно поинтересоваться по поводу:

1) "Пропишите путь к директории export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"

Где это сделать? Создать в директории /Users/home файл с названием .bash_profile, открыть этот файл и прописть путь к нужной директории в формате: " export PATH=/path/to/location:$PATH " ??????????????????????

2) " Команда source ~/.profile ". Это вообще не понял, что означает. Если просто вбить в консоль, то файл не найден.

Comment: Если ~/.bash_profile нет, то его можно создать. В переменной PATH через двоеточие перечислены папки где ос будет искать исполняемые файлы. Если команда source не работает, то перезапустите терминал (ну или всю ос) и файл .bash_brofile прочитается сам